# Get all values table row input boxes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react and I have some difficulties retrieving the values of input boxes of the rows in a table.

On my render method I have a form, table and save all button,

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

      { (this.state.inputList.length > 0) ?
        (<div>
          <table id='configtable'>

            <tbody>
              {this.state.inputList}
            </tbody>
          </table>

          <table id="table-footer">
            <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <td />
              <td>
                <input name="fwdAllNumber" type="number" placeholder="Phone Number"  pattern="[0-9]*" inputMode="numeric" onChange={this.handleFwdAllInput}/>
              </td>
              <td>
              <ButtonGroup className="button-group-right">
                <Button className="config-button" type="submit" value="Submit" onClick={this.saveAll}>Save All</Button>
              </ButtonGroup>
              </td>
            </tr>

          </table>
          </div>
        )  : (<div><br/><h4>No Phone Numbers currrently exist. Please click "Add Phone Number" to begin</h4></div>)}
        </form>
        </div>
      )
    }
  })
```

addRow method adds a row to the render method onPress of "Add row" button

```
addRow(event) {
    const inputList = this.state.inputList;
    const index = this.state.index;
    let rows = this.state.rows;

    const row = (
      <tr key={ inputList.length } name={ inputList.length }>
        <td key={index}><input name={'phone_'+index} type="number" placeholder="Foward Phone Number"  pattern="[0-9]*" inputMode="numeric" ref={(input) => this.phone_$index = input} type="text"/> </td>
        <td><input name={'fwd_'+index} type="number" placeholder="Foward Phone Number"  pattern="[0-9]*" inputMode="numeric" ref={(input) => this.fwd_$index = input} /></td>
          <td id="forwarded-indicator">
          <div id="forwarded-indicator-div" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    );
}
```

I need to get all the values of input boxes in all rows when I hit the saveAll button.

I tried,

```
handleSubmit: function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let rows = this.state.rows;
  const tableValues = this.state.inputValueList;

  let configVal = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
    console.log(this.phone_ + i.value);
  }
},
```

But I get Nan here and on console I get,

```
<input type="text" name="phone_0" placeholder="Foward Phone Number" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric">
<!-- react-text: 162 -->
<!-- /react-text -->
```

I would be really appreciate if anyone could help me onSubmit
Thank you

Comment: show the `handleFwdAllInput` function, are you storing the input values in state variable?

Comment: Yes, I think my concat is wrong in ref={(input) => this.phone_$index = input} I see the value even when I print this.phone_$index on handleSubmit method :( But this.phone_0 gives me an error

Comment: Thanks Shakula! But I get "Cannot read property 'value' of undefined" when trying to get the value like this[`fwd_${index}`].value. How can I retrieve all the values from inputs and store it to state onclick of saveAll? I'm not sure how to retrieve the values :( (I don't want to store values onBlur)

Comment: i think you forgot to bind `handleSubmit` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is in the way you are assigning ref to input elements here:

```
ref={(input) => this.fwd_$index = input}
```

Use this:

```
ref={(input) => this[`fwd_${index}`] = input}
```

Then fetch the value by using:

```
this[`fwd_${index}`].value
```

Check the working example:

```js
class App extends React.Component{

   submit(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      for(let i=0; i< 4; i++)
        console.log('value', this[`input_${i}`].value);
   }

   render(){
      return(
         <form onSubmit={this.submit.bind(this)}>
            {
               [1,2,3,4].map((el,i) => <input ref={inp => this[`input_${i}`] = inp} key={i}/>)
            }
            <input type='submit'/>
         </form>
      )
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
input{
   display: block;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

**Suggestion:**

Instead of using multiple [ref](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html), use [controlled component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) and store the data in state variable, [We should avoid the use of ref](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#dont-overuse-refs).

Comment: Thanks Shukla that worked :) so weird '' and `` was a problem in this[`phone_${index}`]